# Re-assign value inside complex object during runtime in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I currently work with angular 6 and have this method:

```
 public Save(): void {
  this.data.station.parkingSlot.forEach(p => {
      if(p.isAvailable){
        p.isAvailable = false;
        this._carService.addCar(this.data);
        return true;
      }else{
         alert("all parking lots are taken")
      }
    })
  }
```

I want to send data (this.data) with updated isAvailable to false as parameter inside this._carService.addCar(this.data).

Below, you can see how this.data object looks like. As you can see, the last property isAvailable from parkingSlot is not updated to false as it should be.

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "carType": "Spinter",
  "plateNumber": "BUS-XXX-XXX",
  "station": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "STATION_2",
    "longitude": 3,
    "latitude": 4,
    "city": "Oslo",
    "streetName": "street1",
    "houseNumber": 55,
    "zipCode": 31000,
    "parkingSlot": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "PARKING_1",
        "isAvailable": false
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "PARKING_2",
        "isAvailable": false
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "PARKING_3",
        **"isAvailable": true**
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and I want that it looks like:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "carType": "Spinter",
  "plateNumber": "BUS-XXX-XXX",
  "station": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "STATION_2",
    "longitude": 3,
    "latitude": 4,
    "city": "Oslo",
    "streetName": "street1",
    "houseNumber": 55,
    "zipCode": 31000,
    "parkingSlot": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "PARKING_1",
        "isAvailable": false
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "PARKING_2",
        "isAvailable": false
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "PARKING_3",
        **"isAvailable": false**
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what is the solution?I try everything I found while Googling.
Thanks a lot!

Also I

Comment: If the `p.isAvailable` is `true`, are you wanting to set it to `false`? In you code it looks like you are setting it to `true` if it is already `true` (`if(p.isAvailable){ p.isAvailable = true; ... }`)

Comment: what's the condition for updating isAvailable to true? if you want to make it false 
 do if(p.isAvailable){
        p.isAvailable = false;

Comment: I added p.isAvailable = false but it's value inside this. data object is still unchanged

Comment: @Yuniku_123 See this https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-djayls?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1):

Try this! The problem is that you are adding to `this.data` too early. Add to the array when all the information you want has changed :)

```
public Save(): void {
    this.data.station.parkingSlot.forEach(p => {
        if(p.isAvailable){
            p.isAvailable = false;
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("all parking lots are taken")
        }
    });
    this._carService.addCar(this.data); // puts complete data in the this.data
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The issue is you are calling the `addCar` in each iteration however you might want to execute once all the flag is set to `false`.

```
 public Save(): void {
  this.data.station.parkingSlot.forEach(p => {
      if(p.isAvailable){
        p.isAvailable = false;
        return true;
      }else{
         alert("all parking lots are taken")
      }
    })
    this._carService.addCar(this.data); // execute after all the isAvailable is set to false.
  }
```